# Javascript end game when click on image

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, onclick

Hey this is my first time on Stackoverflow!

I am building a small javascript html5 game where you click on objects kind of like whack-a-mole.. The goal is to kill as many "gem green" and " gem blue" as possible in 10 seconds, and when you click on the "gem red".. the game ends and plays a sound.

I got most things to work, except I can't find a way to make the game end when clicking on "gem red".. I have tried lots of functions and listeners.. but to no avail.. can anyone help me figure this out?

Here is the code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>HTML 5 Gem Game</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1">

    <style>
        section#game {
            width: 480px;
            height: 800px;
            max-width: 100%;
            max-height: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
            position: relative;
            background-image: url('img/Splash.png');
            position: relative;
            color: #ffffff;
            font-size: 30px;
            font-family: "arial,sans-serif";
        }

        section#game .score{
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            top: 10px;
            left: 10px;
        }

        section#game .time{
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            top: 10px;
            right: 10px;
        }

        section#game .start{
            display: block;
            padding-top: 40%;
            margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
            text-align: center;
            width: 70%;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        section#game .start .high-scores{
            text-align: left;
        }

        section#game .gem{
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            width: 40px;
            height: 44px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        section#game .gem.green{
            background: url('img/Gem Green.png') no-repeat top left;
        }

        section#game .gem.blue{
            background: url('img/Gem Blue.png') no-repeat top left;
        }

        section#game .gem.red{
            background: url('img/Gem Red.png') no-repeat top left;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        function addEvent(element, event, delegate ) {
            if (typeof (window.event) != 'undefined' && element.attachEvent)
                element.attachEvent('on' + event, delegate);
            else
                element.addEventListener(event, delegate, false);
        }

        function Game(){
            var game = document.querySelector("section#game");
            var score = game.querySelector("section#game span.score");
            var high_scores = game.querySelector("section#game ol.high-scores");
            var time = game.querySelector("section#game span.time");
            var start = game.querySelector("section#game span.start");

            function Gem(Class, Value, MaxTTL) {
                this.Class = Class;
                this.Value = Value;
                this.MaxTTL = MaxTTL;
            };

            var gems = new Array();
            gems[0] = new Gem('green', 10, 1.2);
            gems[1] = new Gem('blue', 20, 1);
            gems[2] = new Gem('red', 50, 0.75);

            function Click(event)
            {
                if(event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault();
                if (event.stopPropagation) event.stopPropagation();
                else event.cancelBubble = true;

                var target = event.target || event.srcElement;

                if(target.className.indexOf('gem') > -1){
                    var value = parseInt(target.getAttribute('data-value'));
                    var current = parseInt( score.innerHTML );
                    var audio = new Audio('music/blaster.mp3');
                    audio.play();
                    score.innerHTML = current + value;
                    target.parentNode.removeChild(target);
                }

                return false;
            }

            function Remove(id) {
                var gem = game.querySelector("#" + id);

                if(typeof(gem) != 'undefined')
                    gem.parentNode.removeChild(gem);
            }

            function Spawn() {
                var index = Math.floor( ( Math.random() * 3 ) );
                var gem = gems[index];

                var id = Math.floor( ( Math.random() * 1000 ) + 1 );
                var ttl = Math.floor( ( Math.random() * parseInt(gem.MaxTTL) * 1000 ) + 1000 ); //between 1s and MaxTTL
                var x = Math.floor( ( Math.random() * ( game.offsetWidth - 40 ) ) );
                var y = Math.floor( ( Math.random() * ( game.offsetHeight -  44 ) ) );

                var fragment = document.createElement('span');
                fragment.id = "gem-" + id;
                fragment.setAttribute('class', "gem " + gem.Class);
                fragment.setAttribute('data-value', gem.Value);

                game.appendChild(fragment);

                fragment.style.left = x + "px";
                fragment.style.top = y + "px";

                setTimeout( function(){
                    Remove(fragment.id);
                }, ttl)
            }

            <!-- parse high score keeper -->
            function HighScores() {
                if(typeof(Storage)!=="undefined"){
                    var scores = false;
                    if(localStorage["high-scores"]) {
                        high_scores.style.display = "block";
                        high_scores.innerHTML = '';
                        scores = JSON.parse(localStorage["high-scores"]);
                        scores = scores.sort(function(a,b){return parseInt(b)-parseInt(a)});

                        for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
                            var s = scores[i];
                            var fragment = document.createElement('li');
                            fragment.innerHTML = (typeof(s) != "undefined" ? s : "" );
                            high_scores.appendChild(fragment);
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    high_scores.style.display = "none";
                }
            }

            function UpdateScore() {
                if(typeof(Storage)!=="undefined"){
                    var current = parseInt(score.innerHTML);
                    var scores = false;
                    if(localStorage["high-scores"]) {

                        scores = JSON.parse(localStorage["high-scores"]);
                        scores = scores.sort(function(a,b){return parseInt(b)-parseInt(a)});

                        for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
                            var s = parseInt(scores[i]);

                            var val = (!isNaN(s) ? s : 0 );
                            if(current > val)
                            {
                                val = current;
                                scores.splice(i, 0, parseInt(current));
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                        scores.length = 10;
                        localStorage["high-scores"] = JSON.stringify(scores);

                    } else {
                        var scores = new Array();
                        scores[0] = current;
                        localStorage["high-scores"] = JSON.stringify(scores);
                    }

                    HighScores();
                }
            }

            function Stop(interval) {
                clearInterval(interval);
            }

            this.Start = function() {
                score.innerHTML = "0";
                start.style.display = "none";
                var interval = setInterval(Spawn, 750);

                var count = 10;
                var counter = null;

                function timer()
                {
                    count = count-1;
                    if (count <= 0)
                    {
                        var left = document.querySelectorAll("section#game .gem");

                        for (var i = 0; i < left.length; i++) {
                            if(left[i] && left[i].parentNode) {
                                left[i].parentNode.removeChild(left[i]);
                            }
                        }
                        Stop(interval);
                        Stop(counter);
                        time.innerHTML = "Game Over!";
                        start.style.display = "block";

                        UpdateScore();

                        return;
                    } else {
                        time.innerHTML = count + "s left";
                    }
                }

                counter = setInterval(timer, 1000);

                setTimeout( function(){
                    Stop(interval);
                }, count * 1000)
            };

            addEvent(game, 'click', Click);
            addEvent(start, 'click', this.Start);
            HighScores();
        }

        addEvent(document, 'readystatechange', function() {
            if ( document.readyState !== "complete" )
                return true;

            var game = new Game();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="page">
        <section id="game">
            <span class="score">0</span>
            <span class="time">0</span>
            <span class="start">START!
            <ol class="high-scores"></ol>
            </span>
        </section>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The easiest way might be to set count = 10 when gem red is clicked. That would duplicate the 10 second timeout.

Comment: And do I put that inside the function Click(event)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alessio -

You only need a few minor changes to your code to make it work. The example below should help you get started in the right direction. Good luck.

**Changes:**

1. Add an *endGame()* function and move the stop game logic from the timer() function into it.
2. Add a line to the *click()* function to check for red gem clicks.

   ```
   if (target.className.indexOf('red') > 0) endGame("Red Gem - You win!");
   ```
3. Declare the *count, counter, and interval* variables at the top of your Game object.

The code below also has a few minor CSS changes used for debugging which you can remove.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>HTML 5 Gem Game</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1">

    <style>

        section#game {
            width: 480px;
            height: 800px;
            max-width: 100%;
            max-height: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
            position: relative;
            background-image: url('img/Splash.png');
   border: 1px red dotted;
            position: relative;
            color: red;
            font-size: 30px;
            font-family: "arial,sans-serif";
        }

        section#game .score{
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            top: 10px;
            left: 10px;
        }

        section#game .time{
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            top: 10px;
            right: 10px;
        }

        section#game .start{
            display: block;
            padding-top: 40%;
            margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
            text-align: center;
            width: 70%;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        section#game .start .high-scores{
            text-align: left;
        }

        section#game .gem{
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            width: 40px;
            height: 44px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        section#game .gem.green{
            background: url('img/Gem Green.png') no-repeat top left;
   background-color: green;
        }

        section#game .gem.blue{
            background: url('img/Gem Blue.png') no-repeat top left;
   background-color: blue;
        }

        section#game .gem.red{
            background: url('img/Gem Red.png') no-repeat top left;
   background-color: red;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        function addEvent(element, event, delegate ) {
            if (typeof (window.event) != 'undefined' && element.attachEvent)
                element.attachEvent('on' + event, delegate);
            else
                element.addEventListener(event, delegate, false);
        }

        function Game(){
            var game = document.querySelector("section#game");
            var score = game.querySelector("section#game span.score");
            var high_scores = game.querySelector("section#game ol.high-scores");
            var time = game.querySelector("section#game span.time");
            var start = game.querySelector("section#game span.start");
   var interval, counter, count;

            function Gem(Class, Value, MaxTTL) {
                this.Class = Class;
                this.Value = Value;
                this.MaxTTL = MaxTTL;
            };

            var gems = new Array();
            gems[0] = new Gem('green', 10, 1.2);
            gems[1] = new Gem('blue', 20, 1);
            gems[2] = new Gem('red', 50, 0.75);

            function Click(event)
            {
                if(event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault();
                if (event.stopPropagation) event.stopPropagation();
                else event.cancelBubble = true;

                var target = event.target || event.srcElement;

                if(target.className.indexOf('gem') > -1){
                    var value = parseInt(target.getAttribute('data-value'));
                    var current = parseInt( score.innerHTML );
                    var audio = new Audio('music/blaster.mp3');
                    audio.play();
                    score.innerHTML = current + value;
                    target.parentNode.removeChild(target);
     
     if (target.className.indexOf('red') > 0) endGame("Red Gem - You win!");
     
                }

                return false;
            }

            function Remove(id) {
                var gem = game.querySelector("#" + id);

                if(typeof(gem) != 'undefined')
                    gem.parentNode.removeChild(gem);
            }

            function Spawn() {
                var index = Math.floor( ( Math.random() * 3 ) );
                var gem = gems[index];

                var id = Math.floor( ( Math.random() * 1000 ) + 1 );
                var ttl = Math.floor( ( Math.random() * parseInt(gem.MaxTTL) * 1000 ) + 1000 ); //between 1s and MaxTTL
                var x = Math.floor( ( Math.random() * ( game.offsetWidth - 40 ) ) );
                var y = Math.floor( ( Math.random() * ( game.offsetHeight -  44 ) ) );

                var fragment = document.createElement('span');
                fragment.id = "gem-" + id;
                fragment.setAttribute('class', "gem " + gem.Class);
                fragment.setAttribute('data-value', gem.Value);

                game.appendChild(fragment);

                fragment.style.left = x + "px";
                fragment.style.top = y + "px";

                setTimeout( function(){
                    Remove(fragment.id);
                }, ttl)
            }

            <!-- parse high score keeper -->
            function HighScores() {
                if(typeof(Storage)!=="undefined"){
                    var scores = false;
                    if(localStorage["high-scores"]) {
                        high_scores.style.display = "block";
                        high_scores.innerHTML = '';
                        scores = JSON.parse(localStorage["high-scores"]);
                        scores = scores.sort(function(a,b){return parseInt(b)-parseInt(a)});

                        for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
                            var s = scores[i];
                            var fragment = document.createElement('li');
                            fragment.innerHTML = (typeof(s) != "undefined" ? s : "" );
                            high_scores.appendChild(fragment);
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    high_scores.style.display = "none";
                }
            }

            function UpdateScore() {
                if(typeof(Storage)!=="undefined"){
                    var current = parseInt(score.innerHTML);
                    var scores = false;
                    if(localStorage["high-scores"]) {

                        scores = JSON.parse(localStorage["high-scores"]);
                        scores = scores.sort(function(a,b){return parseInt(b)-parseInt(a)});

                        for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
                            var s = parseInt(scores[i]);

                            var val = (!isNaN(s) ? s : 0 );
                            if(current > val)
                            {
                                val = current;
                                scores.splice(i, 0, parseInt(current));
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                        scores.length = 10;
                        localStorage["high-scores"] = JSON.stringify(scores);

                    } else {
                        var scores = new Array();
                        scores[0] = current;
                        localStorage["high-scores"] = JSON.stringify(scores);
                    }

                    HighScores();
                }
            }

            function Stop(interval) {
                clearInterval(interval);
            }
   
            function endGame( msg ) {
    count = 0;
    Stop(interval);
                Stop(counter);
       var left = document.querySelectorAll("section#game .gem");
                for (var i = 0; i < left.length; i++) {
     if(left[i] && left[i].parentNode) {
      left[i].parentNode.removeChild(left[i]);
                    }
                }
                time.innerHTML = msg || "Game Over!";
                start.style.display = "block";
                UpdateScore();
   }
   
            this.Start = function() {
                score.innerHTML = "0";
                start.style.display = "none";
                interval = setInterval(Spawn, 750);

                count = 10;
                counter = null;

                function timer()
                {
                    count = count-1;
                    if (count <= 0)
                    {
                        endGame();

                        return;
                    } else {
                        time.innerHTML = count + "s left";
                    }
                }

                counter = setInterval(timer, 1000);

                setTimeout( function(){
                    Stop(interval);
                }, count * 1000)
            };

            addEvent(game, 'click', Click);
            addEvent(start, 'click', this.Start);
            HighScores();
        }

        addEvent(document, 'readystatechange', function() {
            if ( document.readyState !== "complete" )
                return true;

            var game = new Game();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="page">
        <section id="game">
            <span class="score">0</span>
            <span class="time">0</span>
            <span class="start">START!
            <ol class="high-scores"></ol>
            </span>
        </section>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Grazie mille! I can't believe all the headache for such a simple fix.. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For starters, you shouldn't include a style sheet and your entire HTML file since neither is relevant and you should use a canvas element instead of this chaotic use of CSS and html elements, which would allow the size of your code to be halved. Furthermore, you should be able to fix this by just changing some global boolean variable to false when the red gem is clicked and when the boolean variable is false (this if statement belongs at the end of your game loop) you call Stop(arg)/clearInterval(arg). Given that your current code doesn't seem to have a global boolean variable indicating game state (using an enumeration would generally be a cleaner solution but a simple boolean seems to suit this case)

Comment: So I create a boolean value you are saying? Or change an existing one?